# Open site information in Webdriver (selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to to screenshot the URL in selenium with URL and Site Information as shown in the screenshot. But I am not sure how to open 'View site information' menu in chromedriver.

[image: Need to open this menu]

```
    import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
        if __name__ == "__main__":
             im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,510,510)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
             im.save('g.png')
```

I wrote this code to take screenshot of particular portion of screen.

Comment: So what happened to the code which you wrote?

Comment: I think what you'r asking doesn't matches to anything that is asked.
I want to click on the "view site infomation" in selenium webdriver to open that menu. Do you have any idea about that

Comment: What kind of info are you trying to grab from view site information? Or you just want to open it?

Comment: @AyyanKhan Do you really understand why and how is Selenium used? Do you understand viewport? Try reading the selenium docs and come back to the question. Perhaps as per your code trials within this question have nothing to do with Selenium.

Comment: @DebanjanB I understands, but this question doesn't have code only. :)
I understand both :)

Comment: @AnkDasCo Yes I just want to open it and take screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is impossible with Selenium, because Selenium is about only the browser view port. But you can try Robot framework to achieve your goal. Please have a look on the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/#introduction).

---

***EDIT:***

So, after a while I have found a solution to your problem, but.. in Java:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/Register.html"); // open web page
    Thread.sleep(3000); // pause to wait until page will be loaded

    Robot robot = new Robot(); // use Robot class

    // press 'Shift + Alt + t'
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    Thread.sleep(500);

    // press 2 times 'Tab'
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    Thread.sleep(500);

    // press 'Enter'
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image: img]

I have used a shortcut from Chrome [shortcut keys](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) and a little bit magic. It is not Python, but you can also run Java code in Python or use Java.

---

***Conclusion:***

As you can see it is not real Selenium things to work with elements outside the view port. Sometimes it is possible using tricks to retrieve information outside view port, but Selenium is not about this.

Comment: Thanks , this is most relevant.. I used pyautowin to locate that element and clicked that.